# Probability of 2 simultaneous conditional probabilities for the same event

Tags: conditional-probability

[image: see image]Suppose I have lamp L and two independent switches A and B. Both switches have a bit of a loose contact. From experience, I know that the probability of switch A turning on the lamp is 60% and switch B 70%. Hence: P(L|A) = 0.6 and P(L|B) = 0.7 if I write that correctly.

What is the probability of the lamp turning on when I press A and B simultaneously? And how do I write that? P(L|A and B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes easier when you write down the probabilities of the lamp *not* turning on, an event which we call $L^C$:

$P(L^C|A) = 0.4$ and $P(L^C|B)=0.3$.

Now if both $A$ and $B$ happen, it is even more unlikely that the lamp will not turn on. To know how unlikely, we can simply multiply the probabilities due to the independence of A and B:

$$P(L^C|A,B) = P(L^C|A) \times P(L^C|B) = 0.12 = 1-P(L|A,B) \iff P(L|A,B) = 0.88$$

Alternatively, you can consider the three separate events that lead to $L$ in order to calculate the probability of interest: One switch turns the light on and the other one doesn't (two different events) and both turn the light on (one event) and some up the three probabilities:

$P(L|A,B) = P(L|A) P(L^C|B) + P(L^C|A) P(L|B) + P(L|A) P(L|B) \\= 0.6\times0.3 + 0.4\times0.7+0.7\times0.6 = 0.88$

Comment: That’s great, thnx!

Comment: You can accept the answer, if it helps you

Comment: I’m new on Stackexchange so I didn’t know I could accept an answer. I pressed the green tick in the sidebar under the score, is that what you mean? Thnx again!